# Advantage of setting font-size to greater than 100%

Tags: css, responsive-design

In this very awesome [guide to developing a responsive design](http://paulstamatiou.com/responsive-retina-blog-development-part-1), the author discusses setting  a fixed column width that becomes fluid at smaller screen sizes:

> Content is 37.62136em wide (multiply that with 16px browser default and the 103% font-size I have on content = 620px) until the smaller viewports when it expands to 100% width.

The part that puzzles me is using `font-size: 103%`. The result is that the browser renders the text as 17px, so why not set that manually and calculate the content div's width based on an `em` of 17px? Perhaps using a font-size of greater than 100% has other side-effects I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any secret-sauce in the choice for 103%. My guess is that 103%/17px is what looks best for the typeface.

As long as you are setting everything else in `em` units, you can easily scale the font-size on `html` or `body` to have those changes reflected throughout the site. That base font-size (which I typically leave at 100%/16px) is a matter of preference.